# Is this casting safe?

Tags: casting, c++-cli

I need to write a Util function (in my c++cli app) that converts a String to a Double or Float or Int.

```
template<typename T>
static T MyConvert(String^ str) {
     return static_cast<T>(System::Convert::ToDouble(str));
}
```

Is this safe?
Can it somehow convert 2 to 1.999 and then to 1 if I call `MyConvert<int>("2")` ?
I was wondering why the Convert class isn't templated in the first place? (That would let me call `Convert<T>` instead of `Convert.ToDouble()` for all types)
This is C++/Cli so I can use any convert methods in c++ or .net, but I only know `Convert.ToDouble()|ToString()|ToInt32())`

Comment: The Convert class doesn't use generics because it does more than just a simple cast. There's special logic involved for each type, so using generics wouldn't make it any more flexible.

Comment: There are many reasons that this is unsafe.  For starter, what if your input argument is not a number, there's no checking that's even being done.

Comment: This isn't the exact code, I posted only the things I thought were relevant to the numerical analysis. The string isnt just sent directly this this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this is written in non-CLI environment would mean something like

```
   template <typename T> 
   T GetValue (const std::string& value) const
   {
      T t;


      try
      {
         t = boost::lexical_cast<T>(value);
      } 
      catch (const boost::bad_lexical_cast&) {
         // It's horrible!
         // (...)
      }

      return t;
   }
```

Note that this conversion is efficient, because only the appropriate conversion is done. *In your case, converting to `int` would mean invoking conversion to double (which could, and I suspect is less-efficient than plain conversion to int) and evil rounding by your `static_cast`.*

***Why even tend to do that?***

Try the same approach as I used in my sample, but ported to CLI. Specialize your templates for `MyConvert<int>`, `MyConvert<double>` calls or even make two separate methods *(because writing template function with only **two** suitable template parameters isn't the best way to design your application).*

Each of these methods / template specializations would mean calling the appropriate `ToYyy` routine and returning the result of the according type.

Comment: Why can't I use the same exact method? Why do I need to specialize my templates?

Comment: @Itsik As long as it's not your bottleneck and you don't experience troubles, you *CAN*. But in this terms you also *CAN* write all your code in one line (as long as it works). This answer is just my opinion - how would I implement that and why do I think that would be more effective. Of course, the last decision is up to you.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the answer properly. GetValue<T>() looks like a good method to me that gets the job done. I didn't understand the additional part, why I would want to specialize my Template if I went with GetValue. Were you suggesting an alternative option ?

Comment: @Itsik Oh, of course you can use that `GetValue<T>` if you wish to. I thought the question was to find proper implementation *without `boost` usage* (which could be problematic, because in CLI you don't have universal casting method like `boost::lexical_cast` and, hence you should specialize templated method to acquire the same functionality).

Comment: I'll import boost into my project, about time anyway :)